# Server Sent Events (SSE) do not seem to work realtime under IIS (I am using Python and Flask)

Tags: python, iis, flask, server-sent-events

I have developed and successfully tested a simple SSE Python application using the Flask framework. When using the Flask server, each SSE message is shown real-time as it ought to. When I try to run the exact same under IIS, the output is blocked and only shows in a long-poll like fashion; only when the SSE connection terminates. This happens even when using Localhost, so I don't think this is caused by a proxy or firewall.

This is the Python code:

```
'''
Test SSE with Python and Flask
'''
import flask, flask.views
import time

app = flask.Flask(__name__) 
app.secret_key = "anything"

def event_stream():
    mylist = (x for x in range(10))
    for i in mylist:
        if i < 10:   
            message = "Message # %s" % i
            yield 'data: %s\n\n' % message
            time.sleep(1)
    yield 'data: // END\n\n'
    return

@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    Msg = event_stream()
    return flask.Response(Msg,
                          mimetype="text/event-stream")

class View(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return flask.render_template('ssetest.html')

    def post(self):
        return self.get()

app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=View.as_view('main'), methods = ["GET", "POST"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Below is the Jinja temmplate ssetest.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Test SSE </title>
</head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<style>body { max-width: 1000px; margin: 100; padding: 1em; background: black; color: #fff; font: 16px/1.6 menlo, monospace; }</style>
<body>
<form action = "/" method = "post">
<input type = "submit" value = "Execute Again" />
</form>
<pre id="out"></pre>
<script>
var out = document.getElementById('out');
var color = 'yellow'
function sse() {
        var url = '/stream';
        document.write('STARTING');
        var source = new EventSource(url);
        source.onmessage = function(e) {
    var line = '<p style="line-height: 0.1;color:'+color+'">'+e.data+'</p>';
        out.innerHTML =  line + out.innerHTML;
    var start_msg = e.data.substring(0,2);
    if (start_msg == '//')
        {
                source.close();
                }
            };
                }
     sse();
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is your application connected to IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Actually HttpPlatformHandler has [8kb output buffer](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/7) , so my message is not sent out immediately.

I have to change [HttpPlatformHandler to ASP.NET Core Module](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/105), 
so `web.config` must update to this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath=".\your_program_startup"  />
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

And to start `python` 's application as `aspNetCore` on `iis`, the application need to get environment variable name `ASPNETCORE_PORT` then start http service on that port.

That's all!