# Server sent events not working in real-time on IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, server-sent-events

I have an ASP.NET Framework (4.7.2) MVC web application which makes use of the server sent events technology (via EventSource in JavaScript) to push data from the server to the client. Note: *I don't want to and can't use use SignalR for several reasons.*

First of all: **Everything works perfectly fine and in real-time using the IIS Express web server.** But as soon as I run the application within IIS (v10.0.22621.1554, Win 11), only approximately every 2nd request is being pushed to the browser. It's not always every 2nd request, but roughly. The behavior seems to be similar to this question: [Server Sent Events (SSE) do not seem to work realtime under IIS (I am using Python and Flask)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098492/server-sent-events-sse-do-not-seem-to-work-realtime-under-iis-i-am-using-pyth)

It feels like the IIS is adding some caching or buffering behavior between the browser and my application.

This is the server side code of the controller action which handles the connections.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public void Connect() {
    Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
    Response.AddHeader("connection", "keep-alive"); 
    Response.Expires = -1;
    Response.Buffer = false;
    Response.BufferOutput = false;

    Response.Write("data: initialized\n\n");
    Response.Flush();

    var clientDisconnectedToken = Response.ClientDisconnectedToken;
    var client = ServerEventsHandler.Connect(currentUser);
    var cancelled = false;

    while (!cancelled && !clientDisconnectedToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
        var data = client.WaitForData(clientDisconnectedToken, out cancelled);

        if (!cancelled && !clientDisconnectedToken.IsCancellationRequested && data != null && data.Length > 0) {
            foreach (var item in data) {
                Response.Write($"data: {item.Data}\n\n");
                Response.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
        
    ServerEventsHandler.Disconnect(client);
    Response.Close();
}
```

This is the client side code. Pretty simple and straight forward.

```js
const url = "/ServerEvents/Connect";
const connection = new EventSource(url, { withCredentials: true });

connection.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
    // do stuff ...
}, false);
```

I already tried to disable compression in the web.config for this mime-type as I found as a suggestion somewhere in the internet, but without success.

```xml
<httpCompression>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/event-stream" enabled="false" />
  </dynamicTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution. Entirely disabling the dynamic compression (not just for that one mime-type) solves the issue.